# Lambda expression for getting items from list according to indexes

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it possible to get objects from a list according to their indexes at one shot? For example I have a `List<string> alist`. I have an integer List `List<int> indexes` which has indexes. Is it possible to get a result list from the original list which equals the indexes in the array.

I am looking for something like `List<string> resultlist = alist.GetItems(items.indexin(indexes))` (that's just my imagination, not the actual syntax-sorry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var result = indexes.Select(i => alist[i]).ToList();
```

Of course, I recommend you make it a bit more robust.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = alist.Where((theString, theIndex) => indexes.Contains(theIndex));
```

Comment: @Jimmy, Now that I think about it, @ChaosPandion's solution will perform better or (in the worst case) equally well, so go for his instead (unless, for some reason, the indexes list is longer than the list of strings).

Comment: thats what I also thought. That expression can directly access the list of strings by indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
indexes.Select<int, string>(i => alist[i]).ToList<string>();
```